# Do we know how to determine the $2^{2020}$ decimal of $\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-complexity

In the case of $\dfrac{1}{7^{800}}$ it's easy, to find the $2^{2020}$ decimal, but what about the simplest of the irrational numbers.

> **Question:** Do we know how to determine the $2^{2020}$ decimal of $\sqrt{2}$?

Comment: the algorithm is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Digit-by-digit_calculation) --- you may have to wait a long time for it to finish.

Comment: @Carlo Beenakker, I think this question requires to mobilize a strategy different from that which you propose in your link.

Comment: @Qfwfq Newton-Rapson won't finish before the Sun explodes and won't have enough particles in the visible universe for the required memory storage, but otherwise it is fine. A legitimate answer should produce the required digit *without* computing all the preceding ones and that may be quite tricky since there is no obvious pattern in the digit sequence. I would say the answer is "no" but there is no proof of that either.

Comment: according to [arXiv:0912.0303](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0303) no digit-extraction formula is known for $\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @Carlo : well  it's the good forum, research level

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with arithmetic geometry. Arithmetic geometry is algebraic geometry over finite fields, local fields, global fields etc.

Comment: What does $7^{800}$ have to do with this?

Comment: It was to give the example of a rational whose period is greater than $2^{2020}$

Comment: @Dattier Yeah, but if it were *slightly less* than $2^{2020}$ (i.e., if the corresponding decimal digit weren't obviously $0$), it would make another interesting question...

Comment: Not voting to reopen because the question seems hopeless, but, of course, the suggestion to send it to MSE (implied by the formal closing reason) is ridiculous.

Comment: While there is no known algorithm essentially faster than Newton iteration, one can significantly improve on the “not enough particles in the visible universe” front: the decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$ is computable in logarithmic space, which would mean here something on the order of a few KB. (Better yet, it is computable in logarithmic time on a “threshold Turing machine”, if anyone figures how to build one in the real world.) Timewise, this would be much slower than Newton iteration.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek3.0, could you please elaborate? Where is the space saving for storing the digits coming from?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine It’s a completely different algorithm. Basically, you compute the square root by partially summing a power series, but the hard part is to compute the relevant iterated additions and multiplications without storing all the terms (recomputing some of it when needed). The basic idea of the iterated multiplication algorithm is to do it modulo many small primes and then reconstruct it from the Chinese remainder representation, but there is more to it than that. See Hesse, Allender, and Barrington https://doi.org/10.1016/S0022-0000(02)00025-9 .

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha there might be chance at base two:  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+sqrt%28x%29+at+x%3D2

Comment: @fedja Why is the $2^{2020}$th decimal of $7^{-800}$ obviously $0$?

Comment: $$d=E(\dfrac{10^{2^{2020}}}{7^{800}}) \mod 10=\left( \dfrac{10^{2^{2020}}-(10^{2^{2020}}\mod 7^{800})}{7^{800}} \right) \mod 10=\dfrac{-(10^{2^{2020}}\mod 7^{800})}{7^{800}} \mod 10$$ and I find $7$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek3.0 Because my brain was totally dead in the evening :-) That happens sometimes. No, it is not. Just ignore that remark...

Comment: @fedja No worries. You know, I first asked you about this in a comment, then later when rereading it I realized that it is indeed obviously 0 and deleted my silly comment, and then later I realized that my earlier obvious reason was off by an exponential and reposted the comment again.

Comment: Obviously the answer is the digit $3$.

Comment: @KonstantinosGaitanas : why?

Comment: When I was a student in London I used to attend some lectures by the (great and loveable) C.A. Rogers. Once - having tea and chat with him - someone asked which question he would most like to have answered. His almost immediate response was: "I'd love to know the decimal expansion of the square root of 2"

Comment: I have rolled back the edits to this old question, which seem to be purely cosmetic and done for promotion. Yes the question is appropriate for MO, but that doesn't mean you need to add some kind of "RL" label

Comment: If you are claiming that you can answer this question, then you can either add an answer below, or write up your work as a preprint in the normal academic way, or write it in a blog post and leave a link. Saying "I can answer this, can you?" is not a constructive use of this site, nor is it collegial.

Comment: Well, I would wait 500 years for the math community to find a complex 600-page solution, like for Fermat.